# How to define multiple guards on module level in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I have a nestjs module where I want to define multiple guards using the `APP_GUARD` provider. The example in the docs only shows how to define a single guard. How can I define multiple guards?

```js
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: MyFirstGuard, // how can I add a second guard here?
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide another guard like this:

```js
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: FirstGuard
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: SecondGuard
    }
  ],
```

You might think because both guards use the same CONSTANT (`APP_GUARD`) they would overlap, which is true for other provide keys. however using `APP_GUARD` to register a guard does not mean you can use `@Inject(APP_GUARD)` to inject it to other modules. Because what is the point? The whole purpose of using `APP_GUARD` is to register it globally that's why they do not overlap.